# find_if on vector<Message*> with bind2nd and functor

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector like this :

```
typedef vector<Message*> OmciMessages;
OmciMessages omciResponses;
```

And I have a functor like following which I suspect is not correct :

```
class isMatching{
public:
    bool operator()(const Message* responseMsg,unsigned short transactionid){       
        return responseMsg->getTransactionId()==transactionid;
    }
};
```

then I call find_if and want to use the functor to find something in the vector but only for a specific transactionid that is inside my class :

```
OmciMessages::iterator responseit 
    = find_if(omciResponses.begin(),
              omciResponses.end(),
              bind2nd(isMatching(),transactionid));
```

The compiler does not like it and spawns quite a lot of error messages that are hard to interpret typically for template classes.

```
/repo/stuyckp/ngpon2WW/tools/cm4/tools/GNU/src/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.6/../../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_function.h:429: error: no type named `first_argument_type' in `class isMatching'
```

It worked if I did it like this without a function object :

```
static bool isMatching(Message* responseMsg){
    return responseMsg->getTransactionId()==transactionid;
}

transactionid = 5; //global variable being used. yuck, don't like it
find_if(omciResponses.begin(),
        omciResponses.end(),
        isMatching);
```

but then I needed a global variable transaction id that was set beforehand which I think is not that good a design.
So how is this supposed to be done with the bind2nd approach ?

Comment: How is `transactionid` a global variable? Isn't the `find_if()` call part of some method?

Comment: it isn't anymore if I use the functor, only if i use the static isMatching function I need the global variable to use it inside the isMatching function. As you can see that  transactionid is not declared in that function. The point is that I want to avoid that global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct isMatching
{
    unsigned short transactionid;

    explicit isMatching(unsigned short transactionid) : transactionid(transactionid) {}

    bool operator()(const Message* responseMsg) const
    {       
        return responseMsg->getTransactionId() == transactionid;
    }
};

std::find_if(omciResponses.begin()
           , omciResponses.end()
           , isMatching(0));
//                      ^ transactionId to be searched for
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9fcea948d0b327a)

Note that if you urge to use `std::bind2nd`, or the function object would be stateless, then you don't need a function object as a separate class at all:

```
bool isMatching(const Message* responseMsg, unsigned short transactionid)
{
    return responseMsg->getTransactionId() == transactionid;
}

std::find_if(omciResponses.begin()
           , omciResponses.end()
           , std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(&isMatching), 0));
//                        ~~~~~~~~~~~^               ^ transactionId to be searched for
//      transform to a function object
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc70a84d55babd67)

Comment: This will definitely work, if i can't get the bind2nd to work or if that code is ugly too I'll use this. The code is pretty clean like this.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck one more update you might be interested in

Comment: that convinced me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[bind2nd](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) needs your functor class to be adaptable, i.e. provide certain typedefs, including `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type`, and `result_type`. You can define them by yourself in the functor classes, or inherit from [std::binary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function) to make it easy:

```
class isMatching : public std::binary_function<const Message*, unsigned short, bool> {
public:
    bool operator()(const Message* responseMsg, unsigned short transactionid) const {       
        return responseMsg->getTransactionId() == transactionid;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the operator() needs to be const in order for it to compile right ?

Comment: This works perfectly. I had to remove the const from the template so Message* iso const Message* because the getTransactionId is not const for reasons that might not be so obvious as this is a getter. You could not have known this. Thanks you saved me hours from looking.

Answer (score 2):

Given the version of your compiler, I assume that C++11 is not an option (otherwise the answer is simple: use a lambda).

The old function object binders (deprecated in C++11, removed in C++17) require a bunch of nested typedefs. You need to define `result_type`, `first_argument_type`, and `second_argument_type` as members of `isMatching`, either directly or via the `binary_function` helper (which is also deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17), to use it with `bind2nd`.

You can also use a plain function taking two arguments, adapt it with `ptr_fun` (again, deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17), and then bind with `bind2nd`.

Or just use a stateful functor, as shown in Piotr's answer.

Comment: I am starting to think piotr's solution is better than using a bind2nd in the first place.  Because of all that deprecation you are explaining about.